# Imprimir Y/m/d de un mes completo en PHP

Tags: php, html

Estimada comunidad, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php

$num_of_days = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, date( "n" ), 2022 );
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $num_of_days; $i++ )$dates[] = str_pad( $i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
$count = count( $dates );
foreach ( $dates as $i => $date ) {
  echo '"' . $date . '"';
  if ( $i < $count - 1 )echo ", ";
}

echo(date('Y/m/d'));

?>
```

Con el cual estoy intentando devolver lo siguiente: **"2022/03/01", "2022/03/02", "2022/03/03", etc...** pero se me hace dificil determinar cual es el codigo completo para poder ejecutar y devolver la fecha completa, espero que puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si ya tienes la cantidad de días, es solo iterar en ese rango y hacer concatenaciones.

```
<?php

$y = 2022;
$m = 3;

$result = array();
$num_of_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $y);
for($i=1; $i<=$num_of_days; $i++) {
    $result[] = $y . '/' . str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
                . '/' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

`$result` será un array así:

```
array('2022/03/01', '2022/03/02', '2022/03/03', ... '2022/03/31');
```

Si quieres imprimirlo completo:

```
echo implode(', ', $result); // 2022/03/01, 2022/03/02 ...2022/03/31
```